# Check if directory exists using <filesystem>

Tags: c++, file, directory, utilities, std-filesystem

I have a string that contains the path to some file. The file doesn't need to exist (in my function it can be created), but it's necessary that directory must exist. So I want to check it using the `<filesystem>` library.
I tried this code:

```
std::string filepath = {"C:\\Users\\User\\test.txt"};
bool filepathExists = std::filesystem::exists(filepath);
```

Also, the path is absolute. For example, for `"C:\Users\User\file.txt"` I want to check if `"C:\Users\User"` exists.
I have tried to construct a string using iterators: from begin to the last occurrence of `'\\'`, but it very rough solution and I get exception if path contains only the name of the file.

Therefore, can somebody provide more elegant way to do it?

Comment: Try `is_directory(filepath.parent_path())`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ansewer provided by @ach:

```
std::filesystem::path filepath = std::string("C:\\Users\\User\\test.txt");
bool filepathExists = std::filesystem::is_directory(filepath.parent_path());
```

It checks if "C:\Users\User" exists.

Comment: With C++17 you can also use std::filesystem::exists() for a file or a path (see, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/exists).

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a job for [`std::filesystem::weakly_canonical`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/canonical).  It can normalize a path, even if the full path does not (yet) exist.

You can then call `.parent_path` on the result to get an absolute path to the parent directory, and check if that path exists.

Comment: Yes, I have need a parent_path() method. Thanks